# Getting all Values in LLVM Module

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I am working on an analysis pass and I need to find all [InlineAsm](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1InlineAsm.html) [values](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Value.html) in a [module](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Module.html).

I have tried using [`Module::getValueSymbolTable()`](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Module.html#a2eae745d99681023c4bfbc6e1b0e57d2) but it looks to only contain global and function symbols.

I also tried calling [`Function::getValueSymbolTable()`](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Function.html#a125c5fa248b12013a12b5d6e09f705fd) for each function in the module, but the documentation is not clear about which symbols it contains and it appears to still be missing the `InlineAsm` values I'm looking for.

Just for reference, my current (non-working) approach is something like:

```
llvm::Module M = ...;
auto &MS = M.getValueSymbolTable();
for (auto it = MS.begin(), end = MS.end(); it != end; ++it) {
    if (isa<InlineAsm>(it->second)) {
        // do something
    }
}

for (auto &F : M) {
    auto FS = F.getValueSymbolTable();
    for (auto it = FS->begin(), end = FS->end(); it != end; ++it) {
        if (isa<InlineAsm>(it->second)) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get all the values on an llvm Module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd assume you need to collect all inlineasm instructions (and not module-level inline assembler nodes). For this you'd need to iterate over all Functions of a Module. Inside a Function you need to iterate over all Instructions checking whether the instruction in question represents an InlineAsm instruction or not. Something like http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#iterating-over-the-instruction-in-a-function will help.